# Dialog with multiple tabs

Tags: website-design

I would like to get some opinions.
I need to make dialog with 3 tabs, every tab have different form, some very long and some very short.
my dilemma is, if to make the dialog height change by the length of each tab or to make it the same height for all the tabs even if some of them will have large blank space (see the example...). If you have a examples of websites that use something similar i will be happy to see[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have three options:

1. fix the sizes of all tabs to the largest.
2. redesign your from to fit in a medium size that can handle all the form set.
3. the third option witch I Would love is to make a small animation to push (up/down) the container to fit your forms.